# Install xdebug failing on Mac

Tags: macos, xdebug, php-7.4

I am running MacOS Big Sur (ver 11.4) w/ PHP 7.4.19.  I am trying to install xdebug w/ homebrew:

```
pecl install xdebug
```

but it fails with:

```
5 warnings and 4 errors generated.
make: *** [xdebug.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

I tried downloading source and running make but I get the same error:

```
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.19_1/include/php/Zend/zend.h:356:
/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.19_1/include/php/Zend/zend_operators.h:523:10: error: 
      'asm goto' constructs are not supported yet
        __asm__ goto(
```

I have Googled to no avail.  Has anyone else encountered this?

Answer (score 1):

This is because of a mismatch between compilers. You didn't enough include information about which part was compiled by which compiler, but one of them was compiled by LLVM, and the other with GCC. This causes a [mismatch](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75951).

You need to make sure that you're using the same compiler for both.

Comment: You're probably then running it with the wrong PHP version? Which one is it? `pecl -V` will list them all.

Comment: Add FWIW, when you run `pecl install xdebug`, the output will tell you which compiler is being used. Put the whole output somewhere for us to look at.

Comment: AIP-DWINTERFELD-MAC:~ dorianwinterfeld$ pecl -V
PEAR Version: 1.10.12
PHP Version: 7.4.19
Zend Engine Version: 3.4.0
Running on: Darwin AIP-DWINTERFELD-MAC.fios-router.home

Comment: Ugh, AIP-DWINTERFELD-MAC:~ dorianwinterfeld$ pecl install xdebug
No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/xdebug"
install failed

Comment: I also tried to follow; https://xdebug.org/wizard but make fails.

Comment: I posted a bug report with more details: https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1981